# object element don't have play function

Tags: javascript, html

I write html5 like this:

```
<object data="video/loader.swf" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" id='test' name='test'></object>
```

and get object Element by var testObj = document.getElementById('test');
and then I want to pause the swf file play to testObj.pause(); but it does not work. I know this method can control video tag element, but How do I control Object' swf. thanks a lot.

Comment: Try converting video to `mpeg`, `ogg` or `webm` and using `<video>` element

Comment: object is for generic objects, try to search in the debogguer is this element don't have subfields that could hold the video related fields, otherwise you'll have to go with video tag, or with a library (like a jQuery plugin).

Comment: @Walfrat I have to handle the swf file. so how do i handle  it  with jQuery

Comment: @guest271314 in fact. the swf file is the online show .

Comment: @Helpme123 _"the swf file is the online show"_ ? What is "the online show"?

Comment: I don't know, i meant you'll have to search for a library that handle swf